# Use nested if statement in a while loop

Tags: python

In this code, I tried if the number input is 000 get out of the loop with a nested if statement but it doesn't work. get this error: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

```
var=1;

while var==1: 
    num=int(input("Enter a number:"))

    if (isinstance(num, int)):
        print("your input number:",num)
        if(num==000):
          break       
 else:
  print('incorrect!!!')
```

Comment: Try to  space "else"  x4

Comment: Pay attention to indentation, [it is utterly important](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3). Also, `while` and `for` areallowed to have an `else` clause.

Comment: I tried this but get same error @acruma

Comment: Is your `else` supposed to pair with your first `if`, your second `if`, or your `while` loop?

Comment: @superHero 1º space "else" x4 . Next space "print" ( into else ) x4 too =)

Comment: Also, `num` is always going to be an `int`, because you explicitly cast it to an `int`. That cast, however, might raise a `ValueError` which you would want to catch.

Answer (score 2):

Your `else:` line needs to be on the same indentation level as `if (isinstance(num, int)):` so that the code knows what the `else` is referring to (for instance, right now it's not sure what the `else` is in reference to, so it can't run the code).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you have not indented your code properly. In python white-space is very important particularly when working with nested if statements/loops. How does the computer know that you are done with an if statement?

Try

```
var=1;

while var==1: 
    num=int(input("Enter a number:"))

    if (isinstance(num, int)):
        print("your input number:",num)
        if(num==000):
          break       
    else:
      print('incorrect!!!')
```

note the print statement is moved and the if else is now in line

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to getting the user to enter a number would be to catch the exception that is raised when you call `int()` on a string that is not numeric:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
        print("your input number:", num)

        if num == 0:    # note, 0 and 000 are both 0
            break       
    except ValueError:
        print('incorrect!!!')
```

This will keep prompting until `0` is entered. Each indent level is four spaces, this is recommended. Also you can use `while True` to mean loop forever or until a `break` statement is reached.